# De-serializing nested JSON to Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize [this JSON](https://bruxellesdata.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=comic-book-route&rows=58) to an array of Java objects of class `Mural` and show them in a list (Recycler View) in my app. Here's formatted example of the JSON with only the data that I need.

```
{
"records": [{ 
    "recordid": "e6b10b2f7cadbe7caec9a0b36e9e7b570c3add50", 
    "fields": {
        "auteur_s": "Dupa", 
        "photo": {
            "id": "7cd8a2bc799826835057eaec21a28730", 
            },
        "annee": "1994",
        "coordonnees_geographiques": [50.8527886675, 
                          4.34530735016], 
        "personnage_s": "Cubitus - Dommel"
        }, 
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

I use Okhttp to make the request and the response is successful, so I use it to construct a JSONObject.
I traverse the `"records"` array in that object, because that's where I find all the data I need. Keys that have a string or an array as value work fine and I can load them into my app's Recycler View, but when I want to access `"photo"`, i.e. a key:value pair nested within another object, I get a JSONException `org.json.JSONException: No value for photo` and my Recycler View returns empty.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
private void fetchMurals(){
        threadExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://bruxellesdata.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=comic-book-route&rows=58")
                        .get()
                        .build();
                try{ 
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String json = response.body().string();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray jsonRecordsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("records");

                    int arraySize = jsonRecordsArray.length();
                    muralArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
                        String jsonID = jsonRecordsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("recordid");
                        JSONObject jsonMural = jsonRecordsArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("fields");
                        JSONObject jsonMuralPhoto = jsonMural.getJSONObject("photo");

                        final Mural currentMural = new Mural(
                                jsonID,
                                (jsonMural.has("auteur_s")) ? jsonMural.getString("auteur_s") : "Unknown Author",
                                (jsonMuralPhoto.has("id")) ? jsonMuralPhoto.getString("id") : "No picture available!",
                                (jsonMural.has("personnage_s")) ? jsonMural.getString("personnage_s") : "Unknown character",
                                (jsonMural.has("annee")) ? jsonMural.getString("annee") : "Unknown year of creation",
                                new LatLng(jsonMural.getJSONArray("coordonnees_geographiques").getDouble(0),
                                           jsonMural.getJSONArray("coordonnees_geographiques").getDouble(1))
                        );
                        muralArrayList.add(currentMural);

                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

I've tried many variations of this but none have worked so far. Could it be a problem with my loop? Or with the `jsonMural.getJSONObject("photo")` that I am calling?

Answer (score 0):

I see now that I was checking if my record had the field "id" whereas I should have been checking if it had "photo". I changed the line in my constructor to

```
(jsonArtwork.has("photo")) ? jsonArtwork.getJSONObject("photo").getString("id") : "No picture available!"
```

Works now.